# Django, Template

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetag

I am beginner of Django and Template language...

Here is my code:

#### base.html

```
{% block news%}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="news-content clearfix">
                <div class="news-title"><a href="#">Манай хамт олны тухай</a></div>
                    <div class="text clearfix>
                        <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/image1.jpg">
                        # here is some text
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">00                              
                        <a class="btn btn-small" href="#">Дэлгэрэнгүй</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="news-content clearfix">
                    <div class="news-title"><a href="#">#title</a></div>
                        <div class="text clearfix">
                            <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/image2.jpg">
                            # text-2
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <a class="btn btn-small" href="#">Дэлгэрэнгүй</a>
{% endblock %}
```

#### news_list.html

```
{% extends "base.hmtl"%}

{% block news %}
    {% for news in news_list %}
        ######## here i want to display last 2 news at row #########
    {% endfor %}
{%  endblock %}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is that how to show latest 2 news at time?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it all wrong.

The `base.html` must contain all the code that is to be reused over your website.For example the files like CSS and javascript are included in the `base.html`

Inside the base.html you are to include a `block` that is to hold the code that varies from page to page.You can use multiple blocks as well,like header,body, and footer.

When a template is rendered,the requested template "imports" the base.html using `{% extends "base.html" %}`.After the import,the `block` defined in the base.html is replace by the block in the requested template.

As per your question,the code you have written in the base.html that defines how to display your news is to come under the news_list.html,under the for loop.

I assume that the news_list is a `QuerySet` ie a result of a database query and contains the attributes `title`,`content` etc

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block news %}
    {% for news in news_list %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="news-content clearfix">
                    <div class="news-title"><a href="#">{{ news.title }}</a></div>
                    <div class="text clearfix>
                        <img src="{{STATIC_URL}}img/image1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">00                              
                        <a class="btn btn-small" href="#">{{ whatever }}</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

And your base.html

```
<html>
    CSS,JS here if any
    <body>
        {% block news %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```